# Double sqrt solution in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sqrt

I would like to know how can I get both the positive and the negative solution from a sqrt in Matlab.

For example if I have:

```
sin(a) = sqrt(1-cos(a)^2);
```

Comment: So what is the result that you expect to get in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB (and every other programming language that I know of) only returns the [principal square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) of `x` when calling `sqrt(x)` or equivalent.

How you'd write *the* square root of `x` mathematically, is

```
s = ±√x
```

which is just a shorthand for writing the whole solution set

```
s = {+√x -√x}
```

In MATLAB, you'd write it the same as this last case, but with slightly different syntax,

```
s = [+sqrt(x) -sqrt(x)]
```

which can be computed more efficiently if you "factor out" the `sqrt`:

```
s = sqrt(x) * [1 -1]
```

So, for your case,

```
s = sqrt(1-cos(a)^2) * [1 -1]
```

or, if you so desire,

```
s = sin(acos(a)) * [1 -1]
```

which is a tad slower, but perhaps more readable (and actually a bit more accurate as well).

Now of course, if you can somehow find the components whose quotient results in the value of your cosine, then you wouldn't have to deal with all this messy business of course....

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sqrt.html) don't say anything specific about always only providing the positive square root but it does seem like a fair assumption in which case you can get the negative square  pretty easily like this:

```
p = sqrt(1-cos(a)^2);
n = -sqrt(1-cos(a)^2);
```

btw assigning to `sin(a)` like that is going to create a variable called `sin` which will hide the `sin` function leading to many possible errors, so I would highly recommend choosing a different variable name.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I asked it on a wrong way.
I am working on the inverse kinematics of a robot and having already the value of the 
    cos_a (not the a!) 

I have to find the values of 

     sin_a.

I rewrote them in order to show that they are not functions but variables, thanks for the note Dan.

Answer (score 0):

`sqrt` does not solve equations, only gives numerical output. You will need to formulate your equation as you need it, and then you can use `sqrt(...)` `-1*sqrt(...)` to give your positive and negative outputs.